# Visual Studio 2012 Watch Variables collapsing

Tags: visual-studio-2012, watch

This will sound like a simple question but I'm stumped.
Visual Studio 2012 (c#) is automatically collapsing the watch variables with each change. Is there a way to keep the variables open so I can view the changes without having to constantly click the Plus button over-and-over again? This didn't happen in VS2010.

Thank you for your advice!

Richard

PS: I've never seen an solution for this problem! Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever find a work around for this? It's been bugging me for so long but I've always put up with it.

Comment: Sorry. No. I don't think so. I think it was that computer and that installation of visual studio... It was for a pretty messed up consulting job I had so I'm not surprised if someone configured it that way! LOL!

Comment: No worries, and thanks for following up :)